# MySQL: Merge 3 Query Results by Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 different queries that basically sort the same results by different parameters and I would like MySQL to return their results merged into 3 different columns:

```
SELECT `text` AS `popular` FROM `searches` WHERE `text` LIKE 'Tyr%' ORDER BY `hits` DESC LIMIT 10
SELECT `text` AS `recent` FROM `searches` WHERE `text` LIKE 'Tyr%' ORDER BY `datetime` DESC LIMIT 10
SELECT `text` AS `matches` FROM `searches` WHERE `text` LIKE 'Tyr%' ORDER BY `matches` DESC LIMIT 10
```

First query returns this:

```
| popular |
|    A    |
|    B    |
|    C    |
```

Second query returns this:

```
| recent |
|   B    |
|   C    |
|   A    |
```

Third query returns this:

```
| matches |
|    C    |
|    A    |
|    B    |
```

I would like to merge those results so that I get this with a single query:

```
| popular | recent | matches |
|    A    |    B   |    C    |
|    B    |    C   |    A    |
|    C    |    A   |    B    |
```

This is what I tried so far, but the result I get is totally messed up.

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT `text` AS `popular` FROM `searches` WHERE `text` LIKE 'Tyr%' ORDER BY `hits` DESC LIMIT 10) AS A
  JOIN (SELECT `text` AS `recent` FROM `searches` WHERE `text` LIKE 'Tyr%' ORDER BY `datetime` DESC LIMIT 10) AS B ON 1=1
  JOIN (SELECT `text` AS `matches` FROM `searches` WHERE `text` LIKE 'Tyr%' ORDER BY `matches` DESC LIMIT 10) AS C ON 1=1
```

Comment: Do you want results that are the same in the 3 queries be in the same row or do you want just unify the 3 queries and get a total of 30 records? Please give an example what your data looks like and what you expect for output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select t1.popular, t2.recent, t3.matches
from       (SELECT @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 AS rank, `text` AS `popular` FROM `searches` t, (SELECT @rownum1 := 0) r WHERE `text` LIKE 'Tyr%' ORDER BY `hits`     DESC LIMIT 10) t1
inner join (SELECT @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rank, `text` AS `recent`  FROM `searches` t, (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r WHERE `text` LIKE 'Tyr%' ORDER BY `datetime` DESC LIMIT 10) t2 on t1.rank = t2.rank
inner join (SELECT @rownum3 := @rownum3 + 1 AS rank, `text` AS `matches` FROM `searches` t, (SELECT @rownum3 := 0) r WHERE `text` LIKE 'Tyr%' ORDER BY `matches`  DESC LIMIT 10) t3 on t2.rank = t3.rank
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL [**'UNION statement'**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp), it can merge more then one select's and return it as one output. So try:

```
SELECT `text` AS `popular` FROM `searches` WHERE `text` LIKE 'Tyr%' ORDER BY `hits` DESC LIMIT 10 UNION SELECT `text` AS `recent` FROM `searches` WHERE `text` LIKE 'Tyr%' ORDER BY `datetime` DESC LIMIT 10 UNION SELECT `text` AS `matches` FROM `searches` WHERE `text` LIKE 'Tyr%' ORDER BY `matches` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Without considering the fact that the query returns an error due to ORDER BY statement, this is exactly not what I'm looking for since I want to return the 3 query results organized into 3 columns.